# How to deal with a colleague with a very bossy attitude

Tags: software-development, employer-relations, leadership, co-op

I do apologize if I'm not following the format, but I need something that I can use as a baseline for the future.

I work for a quite big software company, and among the projects task we are assigned to do we also have a personal development plan. The personal development plan can convey attending courses, learning new software tools etc. This time I'm contributing to a small project where to which I have to allocate one day per week for six weeks, it doesn't matter which day of the week.

It's probably worth to clarify that this side project doesn't have an impact on anything, apart from the fact that since you write and commit code it proves you're learning something. This is what it is.

As I said this is a side project, I'm currently though working on my main project which clearly has its own challenges that I actually have to sort out.

So this is how currently my time is allocated...

There's a colleague with who I work in both projects, of which I always had a good opinion (and I still have) but I've never worked with him in any projects before the ones I mentioned.

He's one of those guys who has a clear attitude towards management, but currently we have the same role (both engineers but he's slightly more senior though).

We are supposed to cooperate in general but I've noticed he tends to somehow to assign me tasks that in one way or another he doesn't really want to do, or he gives me the idea he's to busy somehow to do.

An example is the following, last week I needed the output of one of his modules to test mine, he could have easily provided me just some generic (but real) output in like 30 seconds instead with the motivation that in a way or another I need to have the prerequisites of his module installed I spent on day and a half putting aside my task and installing these prerequisites (because as you can probably imagine it happens when installing things). It's worth mentioning that once these were installed I had to spend a further half a day changing his code for few reasons to get the right output to be processed by my module. In few words I would have rather finished my task (which isn't trivial) and later done this integration (which turned out to be non trivial as well), and this means I've delayed my task which had higher priority than this form of integration.

What happened on the other side instead he had to do some stuff for which he needed to use one of my modules. For this specific task he literally needs to execute my module there's no way he can avoid that, so in a situation similar to mine he has to potentially install other prerequisites before running the module. Instead of doing the same thing I did he stated with quite a strong tone that he NEEDS certain thing FROM ME (with a sentence like "I need YOU to PROVIDE ME"). I would have been happy to do provide him what he needs if I wouldn't be doing what I'm doing.

Also after talking to my project leader (which to me has the final say) the sensible approach would be to list all the tasks, making him aware of it, and he will evaluate the actual priority, and he also explicitly highlighted that no one apart from him can actually assign tasks (I'm summarizing).

There are other similar episodes, for example he puts pressure on me regarding the side project instead. For example he once expressed the opinion he would prefer we worked together on the same day on such project, and specifically the very same day I expressed such opinion he wanted me to work on it, but I couldn't... and the answer was "I heard yes anyway..." (I ended up working on it on a different day). The next week I went over his desk and asked which he was planning to work on that project, he didn't give me an answer so I made my own plan for the week. The day after he came telling me what to do, I said I couldn't because of the plan I made and the answer was "I don't care".

I'm not entirely sure I should just ignore the attitude, because I don't really think he's in the position to give me orders, or I should point this out to someone.

The reason I'm asking this question is because to be honest I don't really like this attitude where it appears he wants to show some strong leadership skills.

Comment: I think my question is a bit different from that, because I already say a no or I stick to the rules provided by my project leader. The question is whether or not I should point this out to my line manager somehow. I like some of the points of the accepted answer, but that still doesn't answer whether or not this should be pointed out. As I pointed out he is slightly more senior than me (we are both engineers but he is one level above, but he isn't managing anything).

Comment: Pointing this out, in my mind, could clarify whether or not this behaviour is actually allowed or even encouraged somehow, because it might be possible my colleague is just after a promotion and this would explain the attitude, but I think it's important for me to realize whether or not I can simply say no (thing that I already do) or I can't because in the view of my company I would not be considered as being collaborative, for whatever reason. The bit of "pointing this out" could clarify exactly what I can do, so I can act more light heart. So when I say "no" I don't overthink it.

Comment: Have you asked your manager about this?

Comment: No, and I'm thinking of doing it. But I preferred to ask here first.